# C program output in wrong order Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

I have set up Eclipse for c programming on my Windows machine, I have successfully run a "hello, world" program. However, when I try to ask for user input and run the program the console on Eclipse is displaying in the wrong order.

Here is what I have

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void){

         char letter;

         printf("Please enter a letter:\n");
         scanf(" %c, &letter);
         printf("The letter you have selected is: %c", letter);

         return 0;
    }
```

This program builds just fine, and it runs just fine outside of Eclipse. But when I run it in Eclipse I get the output:

```
E <--- (this is my user input)

Please enter a letter:

The letter you have selected is: E
```

I'm not sure why the output is executing in the wrong order, so any help would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: "This program builds just fine," --> `scanf(" %c, &letter);`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had originally had a fflush(stdout); line in the program, but for some reason the program was still producing the same output. However, now it appears to be working. So I guess my next question is, will I need to add a fflush after prompting user for input everytime?

Comment: Yes, to be sure the order is correct, you have to.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Yeah, Eclipse will buffer a certain amount of output (I don't remember how much off hand) before it will appear in the output window</strike>. Eclipse is communicating with the attached process through a pipe which is fully buffered. It won't flush until either `fflush()` is called or the buffer is full. I found that when debugging with Eclipse, things work best if I put the following near the beginning of my application:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

This will cause `stdout` to flush immediately whenever it is written to. If you want to use that for debugging and turn it off otherwise, you can conditionally compile it:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
#endif
```

No need to put `fflush()` everywhere this way.

### Edit

Here's where I found the solution when I first ran into this issue myself.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#Eclipse_console_does_not_show_output_on_Windows

Eclipse's console is not a true console or terminal but rather eclipse is communicating with the attached process through a pipe which is fully buffered not line buffered. This is why a newline '\n' does not cause the buffer to be flushed.

Comment: Would `_IOLBF` work?  It gives line buffering, so each newline triggers a flush, but doesn't throw away all buffering?  It probably doesn't matter for test programs.

Comment: @Jonathan, I imagine it would work, barring any other Eclipse buffering oddities. I've only ever had a need to do this for debugging in Eclipse so I haven't experimented too much.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I knew there had to be some documentation somewhere, but I couldn't locate it. I appreciate the help!

Comment: The same suggestion worked for me for running code from msys.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like Eclipse is buffering the output of your program and not displaying it right away. This indicates that the "run within Eclipse" feature is not intended to run interactive programs.

You could *try* adding `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf`, but you shouldn't have to do that just to make your program work in a particular environment.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `fflush(stdout);` after the first `printf`. This has a decent chance of being of help, in case Eclipse does not auto-flush after `'\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `fflush()`ing buffers is necessary to keep the console's screen updated ...

... but **please** guys, it's **not Eclipse's fault** in- and output might get out of sync, but the library's in use!

Comment: Well, the problem is that the environment that Eclipse runs the programs in isn't quite identical to the free-running command line environment for some reason, so the libraries are reacting slightly differently to the terminal.  The trouble could be the libraries or the way that Eclipse sets up the terminal window.