# Eclipse - make the fflush(stdout) as default after printf() calling

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, windows-7-x64

Having [same case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684303/c-program-output-in-wrong-order-eclipse).

Is there any solution such that the `fflush(stdout)` will occur automatically after `printf()` instead of add `fflush(stdout)` after each  `printf()` calling  ?

I using `Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers` and `gcc --version gcc (GCC) 4.8.1` on `windows 7`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to disable buffering globally, you can use `setvbuf`:

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

at the beginning of your program.

If you want to do it only for some calls, you can define your own macro to do so, like:

```
#define printflush(s, ...) do { printf(s, __VA_ARGS__); fflush(stdout); } while (0)
```

which puts the two function calls inside a new scope with a trick.

In both cases, you will need to have at least two arguments (like `printflush("id = %d\n", id)`), or you will cause a syntax error at compile time.

**GCC specific solution to the problem above**: you can extend the macro above so that it works with a single parameter too:

```
#define printflush(s, ...) do { printf(s, ##__VA_ARGS__); fflush(stdout); } while (0)
```

This way, you can use it also with `printflush("Hey!")`.

**EDIT**: as pointed out by @unwind, variadic macros have been standardized in C99. Still, GCC 4.8 will understand them without any extra switch.

Comment: Drop the final `;` after the macro definitions. Also, it might be worth pointing out that vararg macros are a C99 feature.

Comment: Thanks @unwind, added to the answer, with a little extra bonus. In my code I prefer to keep the trailing `;`: it's  redundant ok, but it won't harm and prevents silly mistakes when a `;` after the macro is omitted (and I often do, mostly if written IN_CALL_CAPS). I'm interested in knowing why you think I should drop it :)

Comment: I would never recommend (or use) the first form, without `do`/`while`, since it breaks if used as a statement without braces (e.g. `if(foo) printflush("blah"); else printflush("whatever");` doesn't do what you expect). I think it's a bit unhygienic to have null statements and I think some compilers even warn, so I wouldn't include it.