# Unexpected behavior on eclipse console for C language

Tags: c, eclipse, ide, buffer

I'm learning to code, and now i'm focusing on the C language. Recently, i bought a course about it and the IDE used by the teacher is Eclipse. At first i had some problems to run the code, but it was solved with a little research, but when i tried something as simple as put a printf() before a scanf(), things didn't worked as intended, **scanf() is being executed before the printf() that preceds it**, like you can see:

[image: Eclipse console behavior]

Then, i tried to run the code on windows cmd, writing on a notepad, compiling with gcc and running on prompt, and it worked as intended:

[image: code behavior on cmd]

After that, i tried running the code on another IDE, Code Blocks, and the result was the same as running on cmd, it worked like intended:

[image: Code Blocks behavior]

Now, to be clear, **i know that fflush(stdout); command works if i insert it before scanf()** and that it's buffer related (what i did not  understand properly yet), but **i don't understand why the problem exists on Eclipse, but it does not happen on other platforms**. My teacher explained that it was related due windows being a domestic OS and being problematic with professional tools, like Eclipse. But still it doesn't makes sense to me, the same code on the same OS, work on a IDE and don't work on other. It is very problematic to write a imprevisible code in such basic level, quite impossible to trust any result or learn the language properly that way. Can anyone help me with that?

i will leave the code here, but like i said, it is very very simple, just to illustrate the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int n;

    printf("Type an integer: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf(" %d", &n);

    printf("\nNumber = %d\n\n", n);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C program output in wrong order Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684303/c-program-output-in-wrong-order-eclipse)

Comment: You will see such behavior not only when you use different IDEs, you will see it also when you use your console-based programs with pipes and redirections of input and output. Better learn about the buffering modes and use them correctly. -- I'm not sure whether Eclipse should mimick the behavior of CMD or not. It would give beginners a misleading feeling of safety and they will stumble just a bit later on other occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Buffering is not always implemented consistently across different systems. Try this with you Eclipse setting.  It should set stdout without buffering.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); // stdout as no bufferring
  int n;

  printf("Type an integer: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  scanf(" %d", &n);

  printf("\nNumber = %d\n\n", n);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the [link](https://cee.studio/200527-8iq/I8Q7m) to build and run the code.