# Why my C program is giving wrong output but the code is right?

Tags: c, ide, clion

I have written a test code on CLion. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b, sum;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter another integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    sum = a + b;
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is not as like as it would be. The output of the code is:

```
Enter an integer:23
 Enter another integer:12
 Sum: 35
```

Output problems:
1. In the first line there would be a space after the (:) 
2. Int the second line, it starts after a space and also there is no space after the (:) 
3. Third line is also starts after a space.

There is another problem. It is showing a warning for `scanf`. The warning message image is given here: [image: warning message]

It is suggesting me to use `strtol` instead of `scanf`. But when I use `strtol` it shows error.
I am using **mingw**.
What is the solution for it? Please help me.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me.

Comment: The output issues belong to the buffering of some IDE's and has nothing to do with your code, which is fine. There is a very similar and famous issue for Eclipse, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684303/c-program-output-in-wrong-order-eclipse).

Comment: Please pack the `scanf()`/`strtol` issue into another separate question. We need to see the actual code to know why CLion is suggesting `strtol` and why your code fails if you use it with the example of how you use `strtol`.

Comment: You can't replace scanf() with strtol() directly. fgets() then strtol() is preferable. However, for a simple exercise like this, the warning can just be ignored.

Comment: What happens if you place `fflush(stdout);` immediately after every `printf` statement?

Comment: Everything is fine in this code.

Comment: "But when I use strtol it shows error." is uninformative as post lacks code that demonstrates the error.

Comment: If able, run the code like `a.out > output.bin` and type in the inputs (you will not get a prompt) and report a hex dump of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Please, flush `stdout`!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a, b, sum;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    fflush(stdout); // here
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter another integer: ");
    fflush(stdout); // and here
    scanf("%d", &b);
    sum = a + b;
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```